# Get enumeration name by value

Tags: python, enums, enumeration

Are there any standard methods to get `Enumeration names by value?`

An example:

```
class Example(enum.Enum):
    one = 1
    two = 2

ex_variable = 1
```

Given `ex_variable`, can I obtain the string contained in Example.one.name?

Answer (score 379, accepted):

```
>>> Example(1).name
'one'
```

also [see the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes).

Answer (score 46):

To [access the members of enums programatically](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes):

```
>>> Example(ex_variable).name
'one'
```